Is there a way to reset or remove all my commits into the dev branch?
I have been working on different branches and anytime task is ready I commit and create a pull request into the dev branch. Till now everything is okej, but is there a way to reverse or remove all these commits I have done and merged into the dev? Is there a way to clean the dev branch from my side?

Why do you want to remove commits from the dev branch? If you don't have all your changes locally, you will likely have issues with merging it into a branch with these commits later. Are you looking for a shallow clone?

I have all my changes locally and pushed all of them in different commits into the dev branch. But the client is not paying and he owns the source. I Want a way if there is one, to remove all of those pushed commits.

You are looking to "squash" your commits. It means to combine multiple commits into one, before merging a branch in another one, to make it cleaner.

Squashing specific commits
You can "squash" specific commits together using the squash keyword in the interactive rebase interface:

Open an interactive Rebase session, pointing to the commit before your changes
git rebase -i <base_commit_hash>


An interactive rebase interface will open. You'll see a list of your commits. Change the word pick to squash for all commits except the first one. This tells Git to combine these commits with the previous one.
pick 1234567 <message>
squash 89abcdef <message>
squash 13579bdf <message>
...
squash abcdef12 <message>


Save the file and close the editor. This will start the rebase process. Git will squash the commits into a single commit. After squashing, Git will prompt you to edit the commit message for the combined commit.


Squashing a merge
Squashing is also an option when merging branches:
When doing a merge from one branch to another, you can specify that you want to squish the commits
git merge --squash <branch>


Squashing a pull request
In a Pull Request on GitHub, you have the option to directly squash the commits into one commit.


I have all my changes locally and pushed all of them in different commits into the dev branch. But the client is not paying and he owns the source. I Want a way if there is one, to remove all of those pushed commits.
